# "if meta box empty" hide it from front end - WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm displaying values for mail and phone in front end.

How to either hide this or set to `javascript:void(0)`

This is my current code:

```
section id="page-content" class="col-md-8">
                    <h3>About <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                      <ul class="people-single unstyled inline-block">
                                <li><a href="mailto:<?php echo(types_render_field("person-email", array('raw' => true) )) ; ?>" target="_blank" class="hvr-hang"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="tel:<?php echo(types_render_field("person-phone", array('raw' => true) )) ; ?>" target="_blank" class="hvr-hang"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php 
$personalEmail = types_render_field("person-email", array('raw' => true) ));
$personalPhone = types_render_field("person-phone", array('raw' => true) )); 
?>
<ul class="people-single unstyled inline-block">
    <?php 
    if($personalEmail != "") 
    { ?>
        <li><a href="mailto:" target="_blank" class="hvr-hang"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
    <?php 
    }
    if($personalPhone != "")
    { ?>
        <li><a href="tel:" target="_blank" class="hvr-hang"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
    } ?>
</ul>
```

If the email or phone number is not blank then it will display the phone number or email.

Comment: I'm getting an Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='  in this line:

      $personal-email = types_render_field("person-email", array('raw' => true) ));

Any ideas?

Comment: @pevoje, my apologies, try my edit I remove the hyphen in the variable names.

Comment: Hey Howli, no, still not working, just getting a blank page :(